# inserting into a multimap c++

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, tree, multimap

I have been given a mutlimap

```
typedef std::multimap<std::string, size_t, StringLenCmp> wordDictType;
```

in a class and I need to design a function that will insert a word and word length into the multi map.
I know to traditionally insert into multimap, I would do

```
mmap["one"] = 1;
```

or

```
mmap.insert(make_pair("one", 1));
```

but I don't know what StringLenCmp is. It is the class,

```
class StringLenCmp {

public:

    StringLenCmp() = default;

    // sort by length first, and then alphabetically
    bool operator()(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) const {
        return (a.size() < b.size()) || (a.size() == b.size() && a < b);
    }

private:
    // no data
};
```

but the problem is, I have no idea what all this means.

Can someone help me decipher all this.

Comment: That third argument is what is used to order or sort the map.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/

Comment: I do not know which C++ compile you use, but the `operator []` is not available in g++ or the [std::multimap C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap).

Answer (score 2):

As you can read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/), `std::multimap` is defined as

```
template < class Key,                                     // multimap::key_type
           class T,                                       // multimap::mapped_type
           class Compare = less<Key>,                     // multimap::key_compare
           class Alloc = allocator<pair<const Key,T> >    // multimap::allocator_type
           > class multimap;
```

The parameter `class Compare` is the part that is by default sorted based on the key value in ascending order (`less<Key>`) but you can define to do your custom sorting of elements in the map and your `class StringLenCmp` is doing exactly that. Each element is checked and sorted during insertion-time.

Answer (score 2):

It is a functor for the comparison function that "sorts" your multimap.

or simply a class that contains the operator overload such that it determines if any of the 2 elements is larger or smaller or equal to each other.